# Elementor Animated Headline Synced with Background Image Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to sync the animation of elementor animated text widget with the elemontor carousel in wordpress. I have looked far and wide and I cant find a way. There is an article but hidden behind the paywall:

https://element.how/elementor-animated-headline-synced-with-carousel/

I have searched the internet and no guide.

Answer (score 0):

for animation heading in carousel
use this css

```
.swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-contents .elementor-slide-heading {
                display:block; 
              overflow: hidden; 
              border-right: .01em solid #000; 
              white-space: nowrap; 
              margin: 0 auto; 
              color: #940000;
              animation: 
                typing 1.5s steps(40, end),
                blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
            }
/* The typing effect */
            @keyframes typing {
              from { width: 0 }
              to { width: 100%;  }
            }
            
            /* The typewriter cursor effect */
            @keyframes blink-caret {
              from, to { border-color: transparent }
              50% { border-color: #000; }
            }
```

may be class need to change as per you used